# Highlight Html Select on Mobile Devices?

Tags: android, html, css

Html select on android looks like a text . How to highlight this, so that any user will identify to select a option from this element.

Update: I have Changed Color to Blue. Looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the css `appearance` of the `<select>` has been reset somewhere in the styles using `appearance:none`.

This can be fixed by removing the `<select>` from the reset or by giving the `<select>`the following (default) appearance...

```
select {
 -webkit-appearance: menulist;
 -moz-appearance: menulist;
  appearance: menulist;
}
```